# Export multiple armatures to fbx

Tags: animation, rigging, export, bones, .fbx

I'm pretty new in blender and I have this issue.

I've to export a book from blender to UE4, this book has 2 separate meshes (one for the cover and one for pages) and, each one, has it own skeleton. The root bone of the pages is linked to the rotation of the root bone of the cover so, when I open the cover I also open pages with a simple animation.
The problem is that I don't know how to export to fbx: I can export meshes but I lose relations between skeletons and, when I try the "open" animation, it open just cover while pages stay still.

Some tips?

[image]

Comment: It's a limitation of the UE4 engine (this works fine in Unity). You can't import multiple armatures to UE in a single file. But anyway you better use only one armature. You can still use multiple meshes, just export them with the same aramture (each mesh to a different fbx), then select the same armature when importing to UE.

Comment: Late to the party, but I'm trying to do exactly this. It IS possible with Unreal. I know, because I've done it before, and one of my old models still exports this way. I just can't seem to figure out how with my new model.